# Save Vec after pattern match

Tags: rust, pattern-matching, message-passing

I'm using the [`Actor`](http://gamazeps.github.io/RobotS/robots/actors/trait.Actor.html) trait from the robots crate:

```
extern crate robots;    

use std::any::Any;
use robots::actors::{Actor, ActorCell};


#[derive(Clone, PartialEq)]
pub enum ExampleMessage {
    Test { data: Vec<u8> },
}

pub struct Dummy {
    data: Vec<u8>,
}

impl Actor for Dummy {
    // Using `Any` is required for actors in RobotS
    fn receive(&self, message: Box<Any>, _context: ActorCell) {
        if let Ok(message) = Box::<Any>::downcast::<ExampleMessage>(message) {
            match *message {
                ExampleMessage::Test { data } => {
                    self.data = data; // cannot assign to immutable field
                    println!("got message")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

impl Dummy {
    pub fn new(_: ()) -> Dummy {
        let data = Vec::new();
        Dummy { data }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
error: cannot assign to immutable field `self.data`
  --> <anon>:18:21
   |
18 |                     self.data = data; // cannot assign to immutable field
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I understand why my current code does not work, but I don't know what the best way would be to save the incoming data (`Vec`) so my `Dummy` can access it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a [test](https://github.com/gamazeps/RobotS/blob/master/test/test.rs) in the RobotS github repo that shows how to manage internal state for an `Actor`.
The state has to be encapsulated inside a `Mutex` for thread-safe access:

```
extern crate robots;    

use std::any::Any;
use std::sync::Mutex;
use robots::actors::{Actor, ActorCell};


#[derive(Clone, PartialEq)]
pub enum ExampleMessage {
    Test { data: Vec<u8> },
}

pub struct Dummy {
    data: Mutex<Vec<u8>>,
}

impl Actor for Dummy {
    // Using `Any` is required for actors in RobotS
    fn receive(&self, message: Box<Any>, _context: ActorCell) {
        if let Ok(message) = Box::<Any>::downcast::<ExampleMessage>(message) {
            match *message {
                ExampleMessage::Test { data } => {
                    let mut my_data = self.data.lock().unwrap();
                    *my_data = data;
                    println!("got message")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

impl Dummy {
    pub fn new(_: ()) -> Dummy {
        let data = Mutex::new(Vec::new());
        Dummy { data }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a simple point here: your method `receive()` gets `&self` as parameter. You can't modify the `self` object via `&self` as it is an *immutable* reference. In order to change any fields of `self`, accept a mutable reference (`&mut self`) or -- if there is no way around it -- use interior mutability. Example:

```
fn receive(&mut self, message: Box<Any>) {
    // ...
    self.data = data;  // works
    // ...
}
```

But this might not be possible in your case if you can't change the trait `Actor` which `Dummy` implements. In that case you *have* to use [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/index.html), e.g. `RefCell<Vec<u8>>`. But if you can change the trait, consider doing so. The method `receive()` already sounds like the `self` object should be changed to have any effect at all.

If this isn't just a careless mistake on your side, be sure to read the chapters on [Borrowing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/references-and-borrowing.html) and [Mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/mutability.html) in the Rust book, as this is very essential to Rust.

Comment: I am implementing the Actor trait `impl Actor for Dummy`. Because I am implementing the trait, I can not make the reference mutable since this would result in an incompatible type error.

Comment: I can't use RefCell because it does not satisfy the trait bound `std::marker::Sync`. I have found a [test](https://github.com/gamazeps/RobotS/blob/master/test/test.rs) in the github repo of robots. I have to use a Mutex, I will write up the answer myself later today.